# Spam issues while using Postfix as a two-way relay

Tags: postfix

I want to use a Postfix box to do two things:

- Relay mail from any host on the internet addressed to one of my domains to my Zimbra server
- Relay mail from my Zimbra server to any address on the internet.

To try and accomplish this I have configured Postfix thusly:

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, zimbra_ip/32
myorigin = zimbra_server
mydestination = localhost, zimbra_server
relay_domains = example.com example.org
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport_map
local_transport = error:no mailboxes on this host
```

transport_map looks like this:

```
example.com smtp:[zimbra_server]
example.org smtp:[zimbra_server]
```

Now, this works and passes the Open Relay tests. However, I am seeing in the `maillog` that the server is relaying spam that has a `From:` address of `<>` to domains that are not mine. How do I stop this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put in smtpd_recipient_restrictions for some in-bound header checking. There are tones of example on the web, following is an example for relay only host

```
smtpd_helo_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks,
    reject_non_fqdn_hostname,
    reject_invalid_hostname,
    permit

smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks
    reject_invalid_hostname
    reject_non_fqdn_hostname
    reject_non_fqdn_sender
    reject_non_fqdn_recipient
    reject_unauth_destination
    reject_unknown_sender_domain
    reject_unknown_recipient_domain
    reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net
    permit
```

**reject_unauth_destination** should reject email to domains that are not yours.

**reject_non_fqdn_sender** should reject (some) email with improper **From** field.

You may want to remove *reject_invalid_hostname* from both of them if you get too many false positive.

**reject_rbl_client** is another one you should research into. I give you one in the example. You can add more.

That should give you a starting point. Those option names should be self-explanatory. Detail information can be found on [postfix site](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html).

You may even add spam filtering and virus scanner like amavis. Again there are lots of example if you do some search.